# how to get data from one table to another based on one common column in sql

Tags: sql

there are two tables named test1 and test2

test1

```
Name     ID Refnum
CHANDRA  1   1234
Vinay    2   1324
```

test2

```
Username Userid  Usernum
A         10      1322
B         12      1221
                  1234
                  1324
```

when Refnum and Usernum are equal we have to update test2 table username and user id with data from test1 name and id respectively. need a query for this.

Comment: You should _specify_ the expected result. And add a tag for the dbms used.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
UPDATE test2
SET Username = name and Userid = ID
FROM test1, test2
WHERE test1.Refnum = test2.Usernum
```

Comment: tried above query ,it is not working , getting error like sql command not properly ended

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Shreyas Prakash is correct but there's a syntax error in query. Try below query

```
UPDATE test2
SET Username = name, Userid = ID
FROM test1, test2
WHERE test1.Refnum = test2.Usernum
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL, you can use correlated subqueries:

```
update test2
    set name = (select t1.name from test1 t1 where t1.refnum = test2.usernum),
        userid = (select t1.userid from test1 t1 where t1.refnum = test2.usernum)
    where name is null;
```

Different databases have shortcuts, but you haven't specified what database you are using.